# geom_violindot produces obsurd plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I was using see::geom_violindot to visualize some data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(see)

df1 <-
  data.frame(
    Value = c(
      rnorm(25, 0.5 , 0.1),
      rnorm(25, 2.5 , 0.3),
      rnorm(25,-0.1 , 0.05),
      rnorm(25,-0.2 , 0.1)
    ),
    Param = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 25),
    Model = rep("X", 100)
  )
df2 <-
  data.frame(
    Value = c(
      rnorm(25, 0.3, 0.05),
      rnorm(25, 1.8 , 0.5),
      rnorm(25,-0.2 , 0.06),
      rnorm(25,-0.1 , 0.07)
    ),
    Param = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 25),
    Model = rep("Y", 100)
  )
df3 <-
  data.frame(
    Value = c(
      rnorm(25, 0.1, 0.06),
      rnorm(25, 1.2 , 0.4),
      rnorm(25,-0.15 , 0.03),
      rnorm(25,-0.2 , 0.02)
    ),
    Param = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 25),
    Model = rep("Z", 100)
  )

df <- rbind(df1, df2, df3)

ggplot2::ggplot(df) +
  see::geom_violindot(
    ggplot2::aes(x = Param, y = Value, fill = Model),
    scale = "width",
    fill_dots = "black",
    color_dots = "black",
    size_dots = 0.02
  ) +
  ggplot2::theme(aspect.ratio = 3 / 4) +
  ggplot2::labs(x = "Parameter",
                y = "Value")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I found the plot obsurd because:

1. For each group of `Param`, only one binned dots is presented, but each group of `Param` should have one of its own.
2. Seems that all four binned dots plots, each has different number of bins, I think the number of bins should at least be the same.

How can I make this plot look right (comply with the points above)? Does this function not support grouped binned dots?

Comment: I'm wholly unfamiliar with this package, but I took a look for fun, and it seems you can specify location of the dots using `position_dots = `. I think that using `position_dots = ggplot2::position_jitterdodge()` looks best, but is not perhaps the best visualization. I think this has more to do with the scale of the data (group "b" being much higher than the others). Using `position_dots = ggplot2::position_dodge()` may be better but there is some odd alignment with the groups that I can't quite figure out how to overcome.

Comment: @dandrews this function is indeed difficult to use with my real data, perhaps I should use other packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a raincloud plot with fixed dot bins. You may want to try using `geom_dots` from `ggdist` and `geom_violinhalf` from `see`:

```r
library(ggdist)
library(see)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Param, y = Value, fill = Model, group = Model)) +
  geom_violinhalf(aes(group = interaction(Param, Model)),
                  position = position_dodge(width = 1), scale = "width") +
  geom_dots(position = position_dodge(width = 1), side = "left",
            binwidth = 0.03, fill = "black", size = 0.5) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 3 / 4) +
  labs(x = "Parameter", y = "Value")
```

[image]